# Data manipulation with date in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have DataFrame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"data" : ["25.01.2020", and many more other dates...]})
df["data"] = pd.to_datetime(df["data"], format = "%d%m%Y")
```

And I have a series of special dates like below:

```
special_date = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(["16.01.2020",
                                         "27.01.2020",
                                         and many more other dates...], dayfirst=True))
```

And I need to calculate 2 more columns in this DataFrame:

1. col1 = number of weeks to the next special date
2. col2 = number of weeks after las special date

So I need results like below:

col1 = 1 because next special date after 25.01 is 27.01 so it is the same week

col2 = 2 because last special date before 25.01 is 16.01 so i is 2 weeks ago

*please be aware that I have many more dates, so code needs to work for more dates than only 2 special dates or only 1 data from df.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use broadcasting to create a matrix of time deltas and than calculate the minima for your new columns

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':  pd.to_datetime(["01.01.2020","25.01.2020","20.02.2020"], dayfirst=True)})
s  = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(["16.01.2020","27.01.2020","08.02.2020","19.02.2020"], dayfirst=True))

delta = (s.to_numpy()[:,None] - df['data'].to_numpy()).astype('timedelta64[D]')  / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
n = np.min( delta, 0, where=delta> 0, initial=np.inf)
p = np.min(-delta, 0, where=delta<=0, initial=np.inf)

df['next'] = np.ceil(n/7) #consider np.floor
df['prev'] = np.ceil(p/7)
```

[image]

Alternatively to using the `where` argument you could perform the steps by hand:

```
n = delta.copy();  n[delta<=0] =  np.inf;  n = np.abs(np.min(n,0))
p = delta.copy();  p[delta> 0] = -np.inf;  p = np.abs(np.min(-p,0))
```

Comment: Marc I have this Erro bu copy paste all your code: TypeError: amin() got an unexpected keyword argument 'where'

Comment: Marc are you sure that your code works for you ?

Comment: That's strange. Which numpy version do you run? [numpy.amin](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.amin.html) clearly has the argument where since numpy version 1.17.0.

Comment: what is your version of numpy ?

Comment: I included a solution without the `where` argument. This should work for you.